# How to access specific request parameter

Tags: node.js, twilio

I thought the format for Twilio's request parameters were being returned as JSON-serialized data --according to the documentation listed for The Response Callback section (http://twilio.github.io/twilio-node/#restResources)

If that is the case I thought I could access request parameters (specifically the body of the text) using JSON.parse as outlined below... however I'm not getting any type of response.

```
var http = require('http');
var twilio = require('twilio');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  var body = '';

  req.on('data', function(data) {
    var messageBody = JSON.parse(data);
    body += messageBody.body;
  });

  req.on('end', function() {
    //Create TwiML response
    var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();

    twiml.message('Thanks, your message of "' + body + '" was received!');

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});
    res.end(twiml.toString());
    });

}).listen(8080);
```

Before that I had tried accessing the parameters as illustrated below... but the body text always returned "undefined".

```
var http = require('http');
var twilio = require('twilio');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  var body = '';

  req.on('data', function(data) {
    body += data.body;
  });

  req.on('end', function() {
    //Create TwiML response
    var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();

    twiml.message('Thanks, your message of "' + body + '" was received!');

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});
    res.end(twiml.toString());
    });

}).listen(8080);
```

And if I just do `body += data;` then I received all of the request parameters grouped together -- which I don't need.

Thoughts? Could you explain how to access specific request parameters?

**************UPDATED********************
After incorporating @hexacyanide's suggestion I ended up with the following code that works

```
var http = require('http');
var twilio = require('twilio');
var qs = require('querystring');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  var body = '';

  req.setEncoding('utf8');

  req.on('data', function(data) {
    body += data;
  });

  req.on('end', function() {
    var data = qs.parse(body);
    var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
    var jsonDataObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    twiml.message('Thanks, your message of ' + jsonDataObject.Body + ' was received!');
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});
    res.end(twiml.toString());
  });

}).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I answered in a similar question of yours, you must wait for the entire response before you can do anything with it. When you're receiving data from the request stream:

```
var buf = '';
req.setEncoding('utf8');
req.on('data', function(chunk) {
  buf += chunk;
});
```

You are receiving *raw* data. It is unprocessed bytes, it hasn't been parsed, and you don't know how much of the total data it represents (unless you've checked content length headers). That also means you can't use `JSON.parse()`, because you will be getting a chunk of data of unknown length that usually doesn't represent the entire JSON string (it could if it were just brackets, or was really short in length, etc).

Even when receiving specific request parameters, you must receive the entire request, and parse it. Modules such as `bodyParser()` from the popular module Express were created for this purpose. If you don't want to use a module, just collect the request, and parse it:

```
var buf = '';
req.setEncoding('utf8');
req.on('data', function(chunk) {
  buf += chunk;
});
req.on('end', function() {
  var data = JSON.parse(buf);
});
```

Comment: Thanks again for the feedback and I'll be sure to check out the Express module; however, in the meantime the new changes have resulted in a 502 socket hang up error. Do you have any suggestions for fixing the socket hang up error? Because I'm still unable to parse the parameters.

Comment: Where are you getting the socket hangup?

Comment: Not sure. How would I find that information? Not sure how to debug it since you can't step through each step. The code is as mentioned above, with your suggestions implemented.

Comment: Look in your stack trace, is there a line number or file that's being pointed at?

Comment: So it seems like it might not be returning JSON data and that I don't need to parse the information because I'm getting a 'SyntaxError: unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse(native)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (../server.js:15:21)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at _stream_readable.js:920:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)'

Comment: I'm assuming the server making the request is only sending part of the JSON and then "hanging up", which is why you get a parsing error. The problem isn't with the HTTP server, so you might want to check with the server making the request.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38277/discussion-between-natehill-and-hexacyanide)

Comment: Still getting undefined even when using qs.parse instead of JSON.parse. When requiring the query string module can I use it right away or do I need to npm install querystring first? Because I looked at my local and global modules but it wasn't listed among them -- wasn't sure if it's automatically included with node.js or not since it's in their documentation (http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html)

Comment: It's here: http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_parse_str_sep_eq_options, if you're getting undefined then the data being sent is undefined.